# Laravel Nova Login Form Submission Error; how to debug?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I am running into an error with Laravel Nova that I'm not sure how to diagnose. When I try to log in I get "There was a problem submitting the form."

[image: vendor.js?id=e15854a5c71630925db0da9393d8055c:2 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/nova/login 500 (Internal Server Error)]

The console does not show any errors. Where should I look to figure out what is going on here?

I'm using Laravel Passport with Lighthouse in case either of those could be the culprit?

Thank you for any help!

Edit: Thank you, Matias, for the direction! It turns out the error is that "Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist."

The response sent:

```
{
    "message": "Method Illuminate\\Auth\\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist.",
    "exception": "BadMethodCallException",
    "file": "/Users/john/Development/jt-backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Macroable/Traits/Macroable.php",
    "line": 113,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/AuthenticatesUsers.php",
            "line": 87,
            "function": "__call",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\RequestGuard",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/AuthenticatesUsers.php",
            "line": 46,
            "function": "attemptLogin",
            "class": "Laravel\\Nova\\Http\\Controllers\\LoginController",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php",
            "line": 54,
            "function": "login",
            "class": "Laravel\\Nova\\Http\\Controllers\\LoginController",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php",
            "line": 45,
            "function": "callAction",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
            "line": 261,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
            "line": 204,
            "function": "runController",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 725,
            "function": "run",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 141,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/nova/src/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php",
            "line": 25,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Laravel\\Nova\\Http\\Middleware\\RedirectIfAuthenticated",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/nova/src/Http/Middleware/BootTools.php",
            "line": 20,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Laravel\\Nova\\Http\\Middleware\\BootTools",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/nova/src/Http/Middleware/DispatchServingNovaEvent.php",
            "line": 24,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Laravel\\Nova\\Http\\Middleware\\DispatchServingNovaEvent",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/src/Middleware.php",
            "line": 92,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Inertia\\Middleware",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php",
            "line": 50,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php",
            "line": 78,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php",
            "line": 49,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php",
            "line": 121,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php",
            "line": 64,
            "function": "handleStatefulRequest",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php",
            "line": 37,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php",
            "line": 67,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 116,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 726,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 703,
            "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 667,
            "function": "runRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 656,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 189,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 141,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/nova/src/Http/Middleware/ServeNova.php",
            "line": 23,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Laravel\\Nova\\Http\\Middleware\\ServeNova",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php",
            "line": 31,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php",
            "line": 40,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php",
            "line": 86,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php",
            "line": 49,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 39,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 116,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 164,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 133,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/public/index.php",
            "line": 52,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/resources/server.php",
            "line": 16,
            "function": "require_once"
        }
    ]
}
```

In case it is helpful, also the first couple lines from the logs:

```
[2022-09-24 20:37:02] local.ERROR: Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Method Illuminate\\Auth\\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist. at /Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Macroable/Traits/Macroable.php:113)
[stacktrace]
#0 /Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/AuthenticatesUsers.php(87): Illuminate\\Auth\\RequestGuard->__call('attempt', Array)
#1 /Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/AuthenticatesUsers.php(46): Laravel\\Nova\\Http\\Controllers\\LoginController->attemptLogin(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#2 /Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): Laravel\\Nova\\Http\\Controllers\\LoginController->login(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#3 /Users/john/Development/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('login', Array)
```

Given some other posts I'm rather sure this has to do with the auth settings. They are currently:

```php
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
],
```

Even when I change the default guard back to web I get the same error.

Comment: Do you have Laravel Passport installed?

Comment: Yes I do @matiaslauriti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! It turns out that if you are using Laravel as an API (if your default guard in the auth config is not web) then you need to change the default guard in passport's config. So, in config/nova.php,
`'guard' => env('NOVA_GUARD', null),` should be changed to `'guard' => 'web',`
After that it should work just fine.

```php
'web' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'users',
],
```

you may want to make a new guard and reference that in nova.php if your web guard is not default.)

Comment: I know this is old, but try to never remove `env` from a config, the idea is that you can change that later without needed a re deploy... so, just put `NOVA_GUARD=web`, insead of deleting `env`...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking at the console, go to the tab `Network` and see the 500 request but check the response. If there is no response, turn on (if you can) `APP_DEBUG` and you should have a full error back

Depnding on your answer, I can edit this answer and help you fix the real error.

Comment: Thank you!! I just finished editing the original with the error response and some more information